# Why my function is not returning the print statement under if

Tags: python, return

`x` is the number of mature rabbits who reproduce 1 pair every month, `y` is the number of immature rabbits that take one month to mature, and `z` is the time period in months.
`def Rabbits(x,y,z)` this function is returning `None`. I am a newbie.

```
def Rabbits(x,y,z):
  for m in range(z):
    if z == 0:
        return ("total number of mature rabbits are ", x, "and immature rabbits are ", y)
    else:
        x=x+y
        y=x
        z = z-1
count = Rabbits(1,1,5)
```

Comment: Cause there isn't any `print()` statement in your code, you're just returning an `str` object, if you want to print the results, write a print after calculating it, `print(count)`

Comment: You're confusing `print()` with `return`. The `return` keyword returns the values you've listed as a `tuple`.

Comment: print(count) is not working either

Comment: There is no ``count`` in the code shown. What do you mean by "print(count) is not working either"?

Comment: whatever I understood I am calling the function by 
count = Rabbits(1,1,5)
and I don't need to define count in function
z = z-1 is reducing the number of months so that the IF condition will work when z=0

Answer (score 0):

```
def Rabbits(x,y,z):
    for m in range(z+1):
        if z == 0:
            return print("total number of mature rabbits are ", x, "and immature rabbits are ", y)
        else:
            y=x
            x=x+y
            z = z-1

count = Rabbits(1,1,5)
print(count)
```

Comment: You may notice you have an extra line--None--printed to the screen after your desired output.  That's caused by your having return print(...)`, following by print(count) in your main code.  That's because print always returns None.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to count down `z` when you don't need to.

I think you meant this:

```py
def Rabbits(x, y, z):
    for _ in range(z):
        x = x + y
        y = x
    return ("total number of mature rabbits are", x, "and immature rabbits are", y)

count = Rabbits(1, 1, 5)
print(count)
```

Comment: well yes that was the issue

Comment: `return` statement still is not correct, it will just return tuple. I guess you need to use `f` string or other formatting

Comment: @RustamGarayev: How do you know it is not correct?

Comment: I just assumed that. PS: I am not responsible for downvote..